# javascript filter object array and return top to best match array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to filter a form object and match against an array of 'Package' objects and return the name of the array of the best matched object.

```
var personA = {
  name: "Budi",
  age: 35,
  occupation: "Engineer",
  noRooms: 5,
  minIncome: 35000,
  maxIncome: 60000,
  minBudgetPMth: 450,
  maxBudgetPMth: 450,
  minSqft: 900,
  maxSqft: 900
}
```

And find match from this array against object keys.

```
var affordableHDB = [
  {
    name: "5-room",
    minSqft: 860,
    maxSqft: 1100,
    noRooms: 5,
    minIncome: 45000,
    maxIncome: 10000,
    minBudgetPMth: 400,
    maxBudgetPMth: 700
  },
  {
    name: "4-room",
    minSqft: 430,
    maxSqft: 910,
    noRooms: 4,
    minIncome: 30000,
    maxIncome: 75000,
    minBudgetPMth: 400,
    maxBudgetPMth: 700
  },
  {
    name: "3-room",
    minSqft: 320,
    maxSqft: 710,
    noRooms: 3,
    minIncome: 18000,
    maxIncome: 42000,
    minBudgetPMth: 200,
    maxBudgetPMth: 450
  },
  {
    name: "2-room",
    minSqft: 270,
    maxSqft: 330,
    noRooms: 2,
    minIncome: 15000,
    maxIncome: 28000,
    minBudgetPMth: 150,
    maxBudgetPMth: 260
  }
];
```

A function should should accept the form data (person object) and this array (affordableHDB) and return the top two best matched array name. E.g. 'Room-5', 'Room-4'. Thanks a lot!

Comment: what means ***top***? please add some use cases as well and what you have tried.

Comment: @NinaScholz edited top to means the person object and array to be affordableHDB array.

Comment: and which property do you want to check against? it is not, for example, `roomNo`, because only one room match. btw what means **best** match? the count of properties, who match or do you have a different rating scheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use constaints and a rating scheme, like count all constraints, who are true and use it as score. Later sort the result and take the top count, you need.

```js
var person = { name: "Budi", age: 35, occupation: "Engineer", noRooms: 5, minIncome: 35000, maxIncome: 60000, minBudgetPMth: 450, maxBudgetPMth: 450, minSqft: 900, maxSqft: 900 },
    affordableHDB = [{ name: "5-room", minSqft: 860, maxSqft: 1100, noRooms: 5, minIncome: 45000, maxIncome: 10000, minBudgetPMth: 400, maxBudgetPMth: 700 }, { name: "4-room", minSqft: 430, maxSqft: 910, noRooms: 4, minIncome: 30000, maxIncome: 75000, minBudgetPMth: 400, maxBudgetPMth: 700 }, { name: "3-room", minSqft: 320, maxSqft: 710, noRooms: 3, minIncome: 18000, maxIncome: 42000, minBudgetPMth: 200, maxBudgetPMth: 450 }, { name: "2-room", minSqft: 270, maxSqft: 330, noRooms: 2, minIncome: 15000, maxIncome: 28000, minBudgetPMth: 150, maxBudgetPMth: 260 }],
    scores = affordableHDB.map(function (a) {
        var score = 0,
            constraints = [
                { keys: ['noRooms'], fn: function (p, f) { return p === f; } },
                { keys: ['minSqft', 'minIncome', 'minBudgetPMth'], fn: function (p, f) { return p >= f; } },
                { keys: ['maxSqft', 'maxIncome', 'maxBudgetPMth'], fn: function (p, f) { return p <= f; } }
            ];

        constraints.forEach(function (c) {
            c.keys.forEach(function (k) {
                score += c.fn(person[k], a[k]);
            });
        });
        return { score: score, name: a.name };
    });

scores.sort(function (a, b) { return b.score - a.score; });

console.log(scores.slice(0, 2).map(function (a) { return a.name; }));
console.log(scores);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks so much. But I want to return first 2 arrays just the name value. Can do so?